# Showing that $(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}+1)^{-1}$ is bounded on $L^2(0,\infty)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

I wish to show that if we consider the symmetric operator $L= i\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}$ on $L^2((0,\infty))$, then the resolvent $R(-i) = (L+i)^{-1}$ is everywhere defined on $L^2(0,\infty)$. This reduces to showing that for any $v\in L^2(0,\infty)$, we can solve for $u\in L^2(0,\infty)$ such that 
$$
\frac{\mathrm d u}{\mathrm dx}(x)+u(x)=v(x).
$$
It is easy to see that we can use Duhamel's formula to get the formula
$$
u(x)=\int_0^x\! e^{y-x}v(y)\,\mathrm dy.
$$
so I wish to show that $T:v\mapsto u$ is bounded on $L^2$. I would like to apply Hilbert-Schmidt type bounds here, but unfortunately, the kernel $K(x,y)=1_{0\le y\le x}e^{y-x}$ does not lie in $L^2((0,\infty)^2)$. How would one prove that $T$ is bounded?

Comment: If you write $u = v\star k$ for $k(x)=e^{-x}\mathbf{1}_{(0,\infty)}(x)$, then I guess that you can apply [*Young’s convolution inequality*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality) to obtain $\|u\|_2 \leq \|k\|_1\|v\|_2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
     |u(x)| \le\int_{0}^{x}e^{y-x}|v(y)|dy =\int_{0}^{x}e^{(y-x)/2}e^{(y-x)/2}|v(y)|dy
$$
By Cauchy-Schwarz
\begin{align}
        |u(x)|^2 & \le \int_{0}^{x}e^{y-x}dy\int_{0}^{x}e^{y-x}|v(y)|^2dy \\
     & \le \int_{0}^{x}e^{y-x}|v(y)|^2dy \\
    \|u\|^2 &\le \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{x}e^{y-x}|v(y)|^2dy dx \\
      &=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{y}^{\infty}e^{y-x}|v(y)|^2dxdy \\
      &=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{y}^{\infty}e^{y-x}dx |v(y)|^2dy \\
      &=\int_{0}^{\infty}|v(y)|^2dy  \\
      &=\|v\|^2.
\end{align}

Comment: So, integral kernels need not themselves be bounded in $L^2$ of the product space to give a bounded operator on $L^2$?

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshine : This is a good example of that, isn't it? :)

Comment: Ah, but the Hilbert Schmidt norm of the operator will be infinite? I think I understand better now.